# Trying to get a work permit in Germany without a degree is a waste of time?

Tags: working-visas, germany

I'm a non-EU citizen, with 6+ years of experience on IT but never finished my college degree. I got contacted by a company based on Berlin for an opening, and i would like to know what are my chances of getting a work permit in Germany. I've been doing some research, and in theory i should be elegible for a work permit, but how realistic are my chances of getting the visa? I'm aiming to 55k/60k per year, wich shouldn't be a problem with my experience.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the salary what counts in your case. You are above the lower limit of ~42.000 Euro for IT jobs. No formal qualification needed then.